# Angular expression in attribute not parsed correctly

Tags: angularjs, video

I want to use Angular 1 to rotate between showing various videos.

```
<video width="400px" height="300px" autoplay loop>
  <source ng-attr-src="{{videos[currentVideo].url}}" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

The attribute is set correctly, but no video shows up. What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is it, but usually there's an ng-*xyz* style attribute which accesses $scope components directly, or there's a standard HTML attribute using curly braces, like this:

```
<source ng-src="videos[currentVideo].url" type="video/mp4" />
```

or this:

```
<source src="{{videos[currentVideo].url}}" type="video/mp4" />
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, unfortunately! In fact, it seems that when I put the first line in your post, it doesn't parse the string as an angular expression at all.

Comment: Have you added an object of `$scope.videos`?

Comment: Yes. And when I add a {{videos[currentVideo].url}} below, it does print out the link.

Comment: Another troubleshooting step would be to take what is output when you have it print out the link and hard-code that into `<source src=''>` to confirm the link and page otherwise works.